# Prospective studies and variable updates: level of evidence

Tags: mathematical-statistics, observational-study

In a cohort study, I'm measuring the apparition of a disease over time and confronting it against an exposition variable, which we'll call X.

This is a very straight-forward analysis where I have the baseline value of X and confounding covariables and dates of event for my outcome (sick/not sick), which I compute as a Cox PH model: `Surv(start, stop, event) ~ X + Y + ... + Z`.

The interesting fact is that I can manage to get updated X values over time, as a time-dependant variable in the Cox model. Intuitively, I'd think this would add information to my model.

But in my team it is said that if you measure the exposition after or even during the measuring of the outcome, the study is no longer prospective.

I've always heard that being prospective is very important in terms of level of proof, but I cannot figure out: how can adding more information to my model reduce the level of proof?

PS : One teammate said it could be kind of related to reverse causation but could not explain further.

Comment: If this question "does not show any research or is unclear", I'd realy like to know how I could improve it. Just downvoting it is not helping anyone (and a little vexing also).

Comment: You will want to look into the way to set up a "person-period" data set.  That should give you ideas on how to incorporate multiple measurements of X and of your outcome.  Regarding causality, I'm not clear that updating your data means it's no longer a prospective study, but prospective vs. retrospective is one among many considerations, as is individual study vs. meta-analysis.

Comment: Thanks @rolando2. ,My problem is not about how (but you get what I'd like to do), but about wether I should do so. I've learned that prospective studies are the ultimate pattern to prove causality, and that it has the best level of proof but in this case it is not clear what is the best choice.

Comment: Could you summarize what you ultimately worked out?